# How would I go about explaining how I want my haircut in Japan?

Tags: words, phrases

So I've been in Japan for roughly 3 weeks now and my hair has been starting to get a little bit long; I've been thinking about getting a haircut for a while but my complete lack of knowledge on Japanese vocabulary regarding hair cuts has deterred me thus far.

So yeah, just what is some general vocab and stuff I should know how to say to try and make this proceed as smoothly as possible? If explaining how exactly I want my hair helps narrow down what advice to give, I need to like near-shave the sides and back of my head, just having the hair around those areas really short in general, but the top of my head is where most of the length should stay. I basically have like my left side shaved entirely and then it stops, forming a hard part for my hair to rest towards the right of my head, and then as you approach the right side of my head the hair starts to fade in length and then goes to same uniform shortness as the rest of my head. My back side should do this as well.

I was planning on showing whoever will cut my hair a couple photos of how my haircut first turned out when I did it and the photo I used for reference for the stylist at that time, and just saying like 「このようなヘアカットしたいんですが」or something along those lines, but I just want to be absolutely sure I have like things I'll be able to say to further explain what I want if that doesn't cut it (no pun intended).

Comment: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4230/542

Comment: The linked question should answer exactly what you were looking for. If not, you can edit this question or else ask a new question.

Comment: That is exactly what I have been doing for the last 20 years: showing pictures. I don't even try to explain... That is too much of a hassle.... It is much simpler and easier to just show some pictures and ask to cut exactly like in the pictures.