# Conversation in barbershop

Tags: translation

How to say " I'll leave it to you " and  "make it little shorter" to barber/hairdresser  in barbershop/salon.
Thank you

Comment: Related: [Getting your haircut in Japan](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4230/getting-your-haircut-in-japan).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To ask nicely to make it a little bit shorter would be :

> 少し｛すこし｝短く｛みじかく｝してください

I will leave it up to you would be :

> 任せます｛まかせます｝

I suppose you come sum it up with something like :

> 少し｛すこし｝短く｛みじかく｝してください、細かい｛こまかい｝事｛こと｝は、任せます｛まかせます｝。

Which would basically translate to something like :

> Please make it slightly shorter, I will leave the details to you.

Answer (score 2):

The answers of others are correct.
If you're worried, just bring a picture of the hair style of another person you like or a picture of your own favorite hairstyle and say "**I want to have my hair cut like this. このようにしてください *kono-yohni-shite-kudasai***".

Answer (score 1):

まかした　＝i'll leave it to you.
もうすこし短く = a little shorter